# When building blackberry10 cordova/phonegap project many files are missing

Tags: node.js, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-10

When building a blackberry10 cordova/phonegap project, a number of files are not included in the build. A number of splash screen images and the file "DEFAULT_BAR_NAME.bar" are not included.

However, if the same process is repeated on another device (desktop PC) all files are included. As far as I can tell, both have identical software setups.

```
C:\Users\USER\hello>cordova emulate blackberry10
[Error: An error occurred while emulating/deploying the blackberry10 project.
[BUILD]   Populating application source
[BUILD]   Parsing config.xml
[BUILD]   Generating output files
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to %HOME%/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[ERROR]   Error: Attribute image: file cannot be found in the list of packaged files: res/screen/blackberry/splash-1280x768.png
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to %HOME%/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[ERROR]   Error: Attribute image: file cannot be found in the list of packaged files: res/screen/blackberry/splash-1280x768.png
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
[ERROR]   Error: File does not exist or not a file or cannot read: C:\Users\USER\hello\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\build\simulator\DEFAULT_BAR_NAME.bar
```

If any more information will help then please ask, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I saw this message a bit late.
But I have a solution for this problem.

1. Browse to the root of your phonegap project (the one containing these folders merges,platforms,www & plugins)
2. Open the www folder
3. Open config.xml
4. Now carefully remove all the declarations for splash and icon for those platforms those are not added using cordova platform add command. For e.g if you have created a project only for blackberry remove all the icon and splash declarations for ios, android, webos, bada, windows-phone
5. Now run cordova build. Your blackberry app should be built without any errors.

I was able to compile my blackberry 10 app in phonegap 3.3

If you face any errors regarding p12 file then you need to follow the blackberry signing guidelines. Or if you got any doubts then mail me 
hansolo.amey@gmail.com